# need to iterate list which is from java and pass multiple values to LIKE clause of iBatis sql query

Tags: mybatis

I am new to myBatis and i need to iterate list merchantOrderNums which is from java,List can contain single element or multiple elements. Then i need to pass list elements to LIKE clause of iBatis sql query.The generated sql query must be like this

```
select count(*) 
from message msg
WHERE msg.spec_id = 50 
  AND msg.mrch_ordr_id LIKE '%ABC%' 
  OR msg.mrch_ordr_id LIKE '%123%';
```

But its generating

```
select count(*) from message msg
WHERE msg.spec_id = 50
  AND msg.mrch_ordr_id LIKE '%ABC%'
  AND msg.mrch_ordr_id LIKE '%123%';
```

iBatis query, what i am trying is:

```
  <select id="getTransactions" parameterType="SearchCriteria" resultMap="transactions" fetchSize="250">
                select count(*) from message msg 
  <where>
                msg.spec_id = 50 
               <if test="merchantOrderNums != null">
                     <foreach item="item" index="index" collection="merchantOrderNums">

                            AND msg.mrch_ordr_id LIKE '%${item}%'
                            <trim prefix="OR" prefixOverrides="AND">
                            </trim>
                        </foreach>
               </if>
                </select>
```

Comment: You haven't really described your problem. What is your task? What have you tried? What is that you've tried outputting and how does it differ to your expected outcome? Does your sql work in the first place?

Comment: Ya, my sql works fine.i am not sure how to write my sql query in myBatis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query should look like this:

```
<select id="getTransactions" parameterType="SearchCriteria" 
         resultMap="transactions" fetchSize="250">
    select count(*) from message msg 
    where msg.spec_id = 50
       <if test="merchantOrderNums != null">
           AND (
           <foreach item="item" index="index" collection="merchantOrderNums"
                   separator=" OR " >
               msg.mrch_ordr_id LIKE '%${item}%'
           </foreach>
           )
       </if>
</select>
```

Note the problems you had:

1. there was `AND` inside `foreach`. This means that elements of the `mechantOrderNums` will be joined with `AND`
2. you probably want to generate query like `msg.spec_id = 50 AND (msg.mrch_ordr_id LIKE '%ABC%' OR msg.mrch_ordr_id LIKE '%123%')` that is with parenthesis around disjunction as `AND` has higher precedence.
3. you used `trim` incorrectly. In this case it is not needed at all. Check the [documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html#trimWhereSet) for reference how and when to use it.